# How to store secret variables in capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, capistrano3

I am writing a Rails app with automated deployment using Capistrano. In the deploy.rb script I have:

`set :deploy_to, '/my/deploy/path/'`

And in production.rb I have:

`server 'example.com', user: 'secret_user_name', roles: %w{web app db}`

Currently the app is private. But assume I wanted an open source app like this. Then I wouldn't want `secret_user_name` and `/my/deploy/path` to be stored in the repo. In the Rails project if I encountered an issue like this I would store the secret values in `secrets.yml` and access them from there. However I don't have access to `secrets.yml` from Capistrano. So I could manually load the secrets file but I'm sure there is a better way to do this.

So my question is: How can I have an automated deployment process without exposing server information using Capistrano? Is there a recommended way to store secrets like there is in Rails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your intention is to maintain your own deployment environment (which you keep secret) but open source the code of the application itself, then I would simply move the Capistrano-related files to a separate private repository. Then you can open source the app itself, but keep the Capistrano config private.

There is no need for Capistrano's deploy.rb, etc. to live in the same directory structure or even the same repository as the app that is being deployed. After all, Capistrano deploys based on the `:repo_url`, which can be anything. It doesn't have to match repo where Capistrano's files are kept.

If you want to give other people (i.e. those that fork/clone the app) the ability to deploy to their own infrastructure, perhaps the easiest solution is to write up a wiki page explaining how they can set up their own Capistrano config. Deployment environments can vary widely and therefore it is probably not something you can do simply with environment variables or encrypted secrets.

In any case make sure you audit and rewrite your Git history if necessary to make sure you won't be leaking any sensitive config when you make the repo public.

Answer (score 1):

Environment variables might help you.
You can put `export SSH_PROD_USER=secret_user_name;` in your preferred shell profile. For example if you use bash then it would be `~.bash_profile`. Then use it in `production.rb` like this:

`server 'example.com', user: ENV['SSH_PROD_USER'], roles: %w{web app db}`

So basically ruby will have all your environment variables

Comment: Hello Maxim, Yes I had considered this but I find it quite annoying to have environment variables for projects because 1) All developers working on the project have to add each environment variable for the project. 2) What if I have 2 projects I run locally? Now I have to have SSH_PROD_USER_PROJECT_NAME = "username" for each project to prevent them from conflicting.

Comment: Either way you do not want to have it in your source code since you want to make repository open. So you will have to share some sort of file with other developers working on this project. It could be whatever you want: requiring `secrets.yml`, `secret-bs.rb` or executing `env_variables_setter.sh`. It's up to you which way you want to make it accessible in deploy script. But I don't fully understand the need of putting deploy script in open repository at first. If someone will want use your app  maybe he should configure deploy by itself since the whole infrastructure will be different.

Comment: @KNejad And according your initial request, no I hadn't heard or seen any special capistrano plugins for those things. Either way it's pretty easy to do by requiring some sort of secret file.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like Figaro gem: https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro

and don't push to your repo your application.yml

Or use an encrypted repo with credentials.

Comment: From some basic testing it doesn't seem like Capistranos' `deploy.rb` file has access to the Figaro environment variables. Since Figaro only gets loaded when you run Rails, when you run `cap production deploy` on its own Figaro doesn't get run

Comment: I am not sure about that, It is suppose that any rake task lifts a fully environment but if it is the case you can use: https://apidock.com/rails/Rails/Application/config_for