# Continuous deployment with public github repositories and travis encrypt

Tags: capistrano, travis-ci

We are looking at setting up continuous deployment for our ruby on rails apps which are currently deployed using Capistrano. They are stored in public repo's on github.

I have read the documentation on how to do this with travis-ci.org and it looks like you do something similar to the following:-

```
gem install travis
travis login
travis encrypt DEPLOY_KEY="password" --add
openssl aes-256-cbc -k "password" -in deploy_id_rsa -out config/deploy_id_rsa_enc_travis -a
```

Then add this to the travis.yml file

```
after_success:
  - "openssl aes-256-cbc -k $DEPLOY_KEY -in config/deploy_id_rsa_enc_travis -d -a -out config/deploy_id_rsa"
  - "bundle exec cap deploy"
```

and this to your deploy.rb file

```
set :ssh_options, keys: ["config/deploy_id_rsa"] if File.exist?("config/deploy_id_rsa")
```

Now my question is, how does this keep the private keys safe.  I'm guessing you only commit the following files to the github public repo.

```
config/deploy_id_rsa_enc_travis
travis.yml
deploy.rb
```

and the that private key should be deleted, not committed.

Is there anything else I should look out for?

Answer (score 0):

The sample code you provided is taking a private key named `deploy_id_rsa` and encrypting it with a password. That password is then stored in Travis as a "secret". This encrypted version of the key is called `deploy_id_rsa_enc_travis`. You can safely commit this file: the idea is that only someone who holds the password (i.e. Travis) will be able to decrypt it.

I would look out for:

1. Choose a complex and impossible to guess password to perform the encryption.
2. How "secret" are Travis secrets? Is there any chance that the `$DEPLOY_KEY` (password) will get echoed to the console output, for example? Can someone log into Travis and view the secrets?
3. Generate a `deploy_id_rsa` specifically for this purpose. Do not reuse an existing key.
4. Ensure the key corresponds to a deploy user that is locked down (e.g. does not have sudo abilities).
5. Never commit the original, unencrypted key: `deploy_id_rsa`.

Also consider [moving your Capistrano deployment to a separate, private repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47581475/4625365). Capistrano allows you to keep your app and your deployment configuration in separate places. That way information about your server infrastructure will not be visible to the public.

Comment: Great thanks....interesting idea regarding the private repo for Capistrano.  Something to consider for the future.